# Empty JSON Object

Tags: angularjs, json

I got an JSON Object as a request that is looking like:

```
 rev = [
          {
            "MovieId": 2,
            "Rating": 1,
            "TimeStamp": 1203077567,
            "tmdbId": 8844
          },
          {
            "MovieId": 2,
            "Rating": 4.5,
            "TimeStamp": 1202841563,
            "tmdbId": 8844
          }

      ]
```

Now when I try to to display the size with

```
console.log(rev.length);
```

I get 0 back but when I do like:

```
   console.log(rev);
```

It is showing me the hole object.

I tried to search for that problem (`JSON` without root, `JSON length`) but got no luck, hopefully you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

My output for console.log(rev); is:

```
[]              
0
    Resource { MovieId=2,  Rating=1,  TimeStamp=1203077567,  mehr...}       
1
    Resource { MovieId=2,  Rating=4.5,  TimeStamp=1202841563,  mehr...}
$promise
    Object { then=function(),  catch=function(),  finally=function()}

$resolved
    true
```

Maybe I found the problem if make after the console.log(rev) :

```
altert(rev);
```

The pop up is empty..

Event if I:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(rev));
```

It gives me only [] as output.

The skript part for rev is:

```
var rev = Review.query({tmoviedbId: tmoviedbId});
console.log(rev);
alert(rev);
console.log(rev.length);
```

And the get from Review is:

```
app.get('/Review', function(req, res) {
        var url_parts = url.parse(req.url,true);
        var search = "";
        for(q in url_parts['query']) {
                search += url_parts['query'][q];
        }           
    connection.query('SOME SELECT STATEMENT WHERE = ' + search + " limit 2", function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        console.log(err);
        return res.send('Error Code 500: Database server connection problem.');
      }  
    res.json(results);
    }); 
});
```

I found a workaround: if I send a https request it works fine.

```
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8800/Review?tmoviedbId=' + tmoviedbId 
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            var obj = angular.fromJson(response);             
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));   
            console.log(obj.data.length);   
            }
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of console.log(rev) ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Paste it in a code block to get better formatting.

Comment: It is the only json?I think you missing something.There is nothing wrong with given script

Comment: rev is promise or Plain javascript object?

Comment: It's from a database request: res.json(results);

Comment: Please paste the script which assing to rev variables

Comment: are you redefining  the variable rev in some other place before the console.log()?

Comment: no rev is never used after that

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem here, It shows the length is 2 and the object also displayed properly.

```js
rev = [
          {
            "MovieId": 2,
            "Rating": 1,
            "TimeStamp": 1203077567,
            "tmdbId": 8844
          },
          {
            "MovieId": 2,
            "Rating": 4.5,
            "TimeStamp": 1202841563,
            "tmdbId": 8844
          }

      ]

alert(rev.length);
console.log(rev.length)
console.log(rev);
```